# Tweepy: Ignore previous tweets to improve optimization

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

**Problem:** Trying to pull tweets via `tweepy` using `Cursor`. I want to make sure I don't pull tweets I previously pulled.

Here is working code:

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ACCESS_TOKEN = ""
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ""
CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""

# OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

csvFile = open(r'filename', 'a')

#Use csv writer
headers = ['UserName', 'Tweet', 'TweetId', 'tweet_date', 'source', 'fav_count', 'retweet_count', 'coordinates', 'geo']

# definitions for writing to CSV
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, lineterminator='\n')
# write the headers once
csvWriter.writerow(headers)


handles = ['pycon', 'gvanrossum']
previousTweets = 
 ['222288832031240000',
 '222287080586362000',
 '222277240178741000',
 '221414283844653000',
 '221188011906445000',
 '205274818877210000']


for handle in handles:   
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name= handle, tweet_mode="extended").items():
        if status.id not in previousTweets:
            csvWriter.writerow([status.user.name.encode('utf-8'), status.full_text.encode('utf-8'), status.id, status.created_at, status.source, 
                    status.favorite_count, status.retweet_count, status.coordinates, status.geo])
print(handle)
```

This takes a long time and becomes unusable if you want to have a PreviousTweet list of over 75 tweets. Does anyone know a better way to filter out old tweets when using `Tweepy` and the `Cursor` function?

Comment: I doubt that the use of list is your problem if you notice a slow performance after 75 requests. But I'll recommend you switch to a dictionary instead of a list anyway, because the lookup-time on a list is considerably slower than a dictionary. Further more, consider posting your question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead - where they review code that is working but you simply need improvements/recommendations on how to make it better. Oh, and I wouldn't store things in a csv file. That's a bottleneck waiting to happen. `sqlite`, databse or `pickle` (of a dict) is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you @Torxed. I'm having trouble grasping dictionaries, do you have a recommended tutorial?

Comment: It's easy once you see it as a list, but instead of accessing items by index - you access them by a given name value. `a = [1, 2, 3]` vs `a = {'one' : 1, 'two' : 2, 'three' : 3}`. And you access the number one with `a[0]` vs `a['one']`. It's great as a mini-database of sorts. `users = {'Torxed' : 'secret password'}`. That way I can look up a users password by doing `users['Torxed'] == raw_input('Enter your password: ')`.

Comment: I haven't found a good teaching resource, and it's probably out of scope for this website. But I tend to teach dictionaries as a dresser where you put your clothes. You label one drawer `socks`, and in it you put.. you gussed it, socks. and to access it, you simply do `drawer['socks']` and out will pop a bunch of socks ^^ It's a bit easier to explain in real life where you can show and tell. Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `since_id` argument to the cursor. 
This allows fetching status that is more recent than the specified ID (
http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.user_timeline)

```
try:
    since_id = previous_tweets[-1]
except IndexError:
    since_id = None

for handle in handles:
    last_tweet = None
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(
      api.user_timeline, screen_name=handle, 
      tweet_mode="extended", since_id=since_id
    ).items():
     # ... persist tweets to flat file or database  
     last_tweet_id = status.id

    # this persists the last_tweet_id in memory.
    # you may find that persisting this to a database a better way to go.
    previous_tweets.append(last_tweet_id)
```